# Deny write permission during writing to file

Tags: linux, unix, file-permissions

`chmod -R -w filename` will remove write permission but if a program opened a file before denying permission, the program can write to file continually even we remove write permission.

Is there any idea for solving this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [mandatory locking](http://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/mandatory-locking.txt) but then the write will not fail with an error, but be blocked indefinitely.

But do not overlook the first paragraph: "Why you should avoid mandatory locking".

Comment: so how the program can find out the file is locked?

Comment: @Ali - AFAIK, your program will not know about it, it will just block on write. Maybe not what you need, but you didn't give so many details...

Comment: it means the program think he can write in file but actually nothing will write to file?

Comment: so if for example 1 program write and another program read from the file, in the middle of this action we mandatory locking the file! the program can read the file(with update!)?

Comment: I think it means that the file will block in the write indefinitely. That is, `write` will not return until the lock is released.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fuser` or `lsof` to see what processes have the file open and kill them

Comment: i don't want to kill the process
I want just prevent it to write to files

Answer (score 0):

Try duplicating it and use the duplicate with a new name instead of the old version.  This prevents the program from altering the data you presumably no longer want altered.  The obvious solution, though, is to simply kill the program.

Comment: Changing the filename won't change anything. `mv`'ing the file to a separate filesystem can cause really strange things (because the original file will in fact still be there and written to in the original filesystem, but no longer visible.)

Comment: You're right, changing the filename won't help, duplicating it and the letting the program go along happily editing the old version that we no longer care about should, though.